# kubeadm is showing [ERROR CRI]:

Tags: kubeadm

kubeadm init
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.26.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
[ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: time="2023-03-01T08:28:38Z" level=fatal msg="validate service connection: CRI v1 runtime API is not implemented for endpoint "unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock": rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1.RuntimeService"
, error: exit status 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

Answer (score 1):

Try the below steps:

1. delete the config.tomal file `$rm /etc/containerd/config.toml`
2. restart containerd `systemctl restart containerd`
3. try the init command `kubeadm init`

Answer (score 0):

[rm /etc/containerd/config.toml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arm1w.png)

[kubeadm init error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtXLN.png)

[systemctl restart containerd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUz6u.png)

[kubeadm init success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIlVK.png)